# How to write scalable code using Entity Framework Core for autoscaling

Tags: c#, .net, azure, entity-framework-core, autoscaling

While learning about writing scalable applications, I encountered a question related to Entity Framework Core (EF Core). EF Core utilizes connection strings, `DbContext`, and migrations when working with a new database.

Consequently, each time a new database is added, specific details such as connection strings need to be provided. In the context of auto-scaling, the challenge arises because the exact number of databases to be added and their corresponding connection strings remain unknown.

After conducting research, I discovered that it is possible to create a `DbContext` factory for dynamically generating `DbContext` instances. The approach is as follows:

```
public class DbContextFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public DbContextFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public DbContext CreateDbContext(string databaseName)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(GetConnectionStringForDatabase(databaseName));

        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<DbContext>(_serviceProvider, optionsBuilder.Options);
    }

    private string GetConnectionStringForDatabase(string databaseName)
    {
        // get connection string for each database
    }
}
```

For me still it won't solve the problem as we have to know the connection strings.

How can we develop code that dynamically generates connection strings and `DbContext` instances to effectively manage the unpredictable nature of auto-scaling?

Comment: Creating database instances and context instances are two entirely different concepts. Creating context instances usually is not something that requires scaling. Please provide more details on what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @GertArnold Suppose I have to design a system where all the writes go to the master database, and all the reads go to another read database. In this case, I have to create 2 DbContexts in the application, one for the master and another for the read database. However, what happens if I want to scale the read database further to include 5 databases? How can I dynamically create the DbContexts and connection strings in this scenario?

Comment: What problem scenario are you trying to solve? Scale-able applications aren't just about adding extra databases. The requirement governs what approaches might work best. For instance for multi-tenant systems I have used a master authentication database (with fail-over replica) where that database essentially stores the generated connection string to the data instance for each tenant.  This would differ from scenarios where I might want to parallelize reads across massive datasets, or support read-only replicas for reporting etc.

Comment: @StevePy The scenario is that I have a master database where all writes occur, and a read replica where all reads are directed. The data is replicated from the master to the read replica whenever a write operation occurs.
I have two database contexts and two connection strings. I intend to deploy this system to Azure and enable autoscaling for database instances, specifically for read-only replicas. Consequently, I need to modify the data context code to ensure that when new databases are added, reads will be distributed randomly among the newly created databases.